# Sequelize: group by while including extra attributes on same model

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sequelize.js

I'm new-ish to sequelize (and dev as a whole), but getting along.

I'm trying to make a query in a messaging chat app that can pull all recent conversation threads (1 message from each), done like this in sequelize:

```
const messages = await db.Message.findAll({
  group: ['userId'],
  attributes: ['userId', [db.sequelize.fn('MAX', db.sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'lastMessageTime']],
  order: [[db.sequelize.fn('MAX', db.sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'DESC']],
  limit: 30,
```

This does group the latest messages properly, but I want to include an extra attribute alongside them, such as the id of the sender. But if I add that in attributes I get this error:

Error: GraphQL error: column "message.senderId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I've been reading about how to include associated models, but I can't seem to include the same model itself. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas about this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo, I do believe I got it to work properly, but it's been a couple of years since I worked on this. Here, I'll post the code that was put into production. You can let me know if it helped you:

`const messages = await db.Message.findAll({
      group: ['oAuthId', 'isAdmin'],
      attributes: [
        'oAuthId',
        'isAdmin',
        [db.sequelize.fn('MAX', db.sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'lastMessageTime'],
      ],
      order: [[db.sequelize.fn('MAX', db.sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'DESC']],
      limit: 30,
})`